# C++ Copy constructing Derived class from Base class

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, copy-constructor

I have a game with few different object classes which are all derived from a base class name Gameobject like so:

```
class Gameobject{...}
class Block : public Gameobject{...}
class Wall  : public Gameobject{...}
class Raw   : public Gameobject{...}
```

Inside the logic of the game I'm managing some part with actual Blocks and Walls but as Gameobject like:

```
Gameobject* wall = new Wall();
Gameobject* block = new Block();
```

And the problem is that I would like to be able to call a copy constructor to copy an object but in the in a way that if I call

```
Gameobject* newObj = new Gameobject(ObjToCopy);
```

it will recognize if the object to copy is a wall/block/somethingelse and copy the data in the wall/block/somethingelse class and create an actual wall/block/somethingelse object.

If that helps I have a variable inside the Gameobject class that tells me what class that object is exactly like:

```
if (genericObject.category=="block"){
    /* cast is like a block and use it like that */
}else{
    /* do other checks */
}
```

Comment: `virtual Gameobject* clone() const = 0;`

Comment: @StoryTeller that seems like a reasonable solution, I'll try now thanks